# Nesting side effect free atomic functions for threadsafe buffer

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

This is more an academical question since I have a working solution for this based on locks. My aim is to create a performant buffer without blocking, based on javas atomic objects / functions. Unfortunatly the Exceptions in the addData method do fire. There are about 3 to 18 fails recorded with my unit test which uses 50 threads simultaniously on a buffer of size 10. Occasionally the test is OK.
I cannot see where I am wrong, since the functions should be side effect free and therefore should return clean results. All fails end up with an empty byte[][] returned. It seems like the function got 'laped' by thread entries once, when fails occur.
If the code snippet ist unclear etc. I can also post the complete implementation incl. unit test.

```
public final byte[][] addAndGetIfFull(final byte[] data) {
    final AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]> buf = addData(data); // buf is immutable if full
    if (_full.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
        resetTimer();
        buf.setPlain(_size - 1, data); // add data to last empty space
        return convert(buf);
    }
    return null;
}

private final AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]> addData(final byte[] data) {
    return _currentBufferRef.getAndUpdate(array -> {
        int idx = _arrayIdx.updateAndGet(i -> {
            if (i == _size-2) { // reached buffer size + leave safe space for last entry
                return -1;
            } else {
                return ++i; // increment
            }
        });
        if (idx == -1) {
            if (!_full.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                //_collisions.incrementAndGet();
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException("Failed compareAndSet while creating buffer.");
            }
            return new AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]>(_size);
        } else {
            if (!array.compareAndSet(idx, null, data)) {
                //_collisions.incrementAndGet();
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException("Failed compareAndSet value '" + new String(data) + "' in buffer " + idx + " - was in use by other thread.");
            }
            return array;
        }
    });
}
```

`

Edit:
The result after finishing with 3 collisions - all Buffers (byte[][]) with no rows shown are completely OK, the others contain no data at all. The exception thrown is always the one from array.compareAndSet(...). The _full.compareAndSet(...) is never thrown unless i move it into the updateAndGet(...) from _arrayIdx before returning -1.

```
Output:

Collisions registered: 3

Buffer #1910115902
Buffer #886611553
Buffer #182387041
Buffer #1756629841
Buffer #670751884
row: 1 = NULL
row: 2 = NULL
row: 3 = NULL
row: 4 = NULL
row: 5 = NULL
row: 6 = NULL
row: 7 = NULL
row: 8 = NULL
row: 9 = NULL
row: 10 = NULL
Buffer #1188792619
...
```

Edit 2:
Variables:

```
private final int _size;
private final int _flushInterval;
private final IntervalExecutor _func;
private final AtomicLong _executionTime;

private final AtomicInteger _collisions = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final AtomicBoolean _full = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private final AtomicInteger _arrayIdx = new AtomicInteger(-1);
private final AtomicReference<AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]>> _currentBufferRef = new AtomicReference<>();
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testMultiThreadsNoDataLoss() throws InterruptedException {
    final int threads = 50;
    final int bufSize = 10;
    final AtomicInteger thread = new AtomicInteger(0);

    DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();
    RefillBuffer buf = new RefillBuffer(bufSize, dh::processData);
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    for (int t = 0; t < threads; ++t) {
        es.execute(() -> {
            int th = thread.incrementAndGet();
            for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
                final byte[][] data = buf.addAndGetIfFull(new String(String.valueOf(i+1) + " from Thread #" + th).getBytes());
                if (data != null) {
                    dh.processData(data, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    es.shutdown();
    es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    System.out.println("Collisions registered: " + buf.getCollisions());

    final int success = dh.getCount();
    final int fails = dh.getCountEmpty();
    
    dh.dumpFails();
    // test if reserved buffer was ok
    assertTrue("Expected "+bufSize*threads+" buffer spaces, but recorded: "+ fails + " fails and " + success + " successes adding up to: "+ (fails+success) + " spaces.", fails+success == threads*bufSize);
    // test no data lost
    assertTrue("Lost data - expected "+bufSize*threads+" entries, but only registered: "+ success, success == bufSize*threads);

}
```

Comment: This question does not make sense as you've omitted variable declarations in the snippet of code, and given no details of what your tests are doing. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought variable declarationss could be derived by the code. I will add that immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

With the lock based approach I presume you are locking the addAndGetIfFull. So there are no concurrent calls.

With the atomic approach, you need to understand that the getAndUpdate can execute multiple times.

```
public final V getAndUpdate(UnaryOperator<V> updateFunction) {
        V prev, next;
        do {
            prev = get();
            next = updateFunction.apply(prev);
        } while (!compareAndSet(prev, next));
        return prev;
    }
```

This isn't a problem if the code executed in the updateFunction is free of side effects. But in your case, it isn't since you are updating some resources like the _arrayIdx and the array.

So it can happen that these resources get updates even though the actual update to the _currentBufferRef fails and needs to be retried. My bet is that this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Good point, but the index count seems to be not the problem, since order is not relevant and the index is always valid as long as the array is valid.I actually found the problem, actaully two problems.
1. Creating a new instance of the array is not sided effect free.
2. It is not guaranteed the thread setting the full flag, unsets it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution, tested it hard on a 48 core Server and it did not fail. The only problem left is, that reading/clearing may take longer than adding, since the below implementation implements a ring buffer, to overcome the problem with creating new instances of the buffer array. There is a exception fired if this happens, but I need to think about a 100% safe solution:

`

```
private final AtomicInteger _collisions = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final AtomicInteger _currBuf = new AtomicInteger(-1);
private final AtomicInteger _numBuf = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final AtomicInteger _count = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final AtomicInteger _arrayIdx = new AtomicInteger(-1);
private final AtomicReference<AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]>> _bufferRef = new AtomicReference<>();

/**
 * Constructor for using flush interval for automatic flush. If flush interval time is set, this instance is thread safe.
 * 
 * @param bufferSize the buffer size selected by user in the profile.
 * @param flushInterval the time span in seconds when buffer is flushed automatically. If set to '0' no interval is configured, therefore the buffer flushed automatically from
 *            the {@link IOTIntervalWatchdog}.
 * @param func the data processing function called when flushed.
 * @param reorder if set the returned buffer will not contain gaps if not completely filled.
 */
public RefillBuffer(int bufferSize, int flushInterval, IntervalExecutor func, boolean reorder) {
    _bufferSize = bufferSize;
    _size = _bufferSize * _cacheSize;
    _flushInterval = flushInterval * 1000; // convert seconds to milliseconds
    if (_flushInterval > 0) {
        _executionTime = new AtomicLong();
        resetTimer();
    } else {
        _executionTime = null;
    }
    _bufferRef.set(new AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]>(_size));

    _func = func;
    _reorder = reorder;
}

/**
 * Constructor not using any flush interval for automatic flush, but with the option to create a thread safe instance. If thread safe is set to true, the synchronization
 * overhead is greater, therefore performance is lower.
 * 
 * @param bufferSize the buffer size selected by user in the profile.
 * @param func the data processing function called when flushed.
 * @param threadsafe if set to true, this instance is thread safe.
 * @param reorder if set the returned buffer will not contain gaps if not completely filled.
 */
public RefillBuffer(int bufferSize, IntervalExecutor func, boolean reorder) {
    _bufferSize = bufferSize;
    _size = _bufferSize * _cacheSize;
    _flushInterval = 0;
    _executionTime = null;
    _bufferRef.set(new AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]>(_size));
    _func = func;
    _reorder = reorder;
}

@Override
public final void reset() {
    _bufferRef.updateAndGet(current -> {
        _arrayIdx.setPlain(-1);
        return new AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]>(_size);
    });
}

/**
 * Adds the data to be buffered and sets atomic flag if buffer reached its limit.
 * 
 * @param data the data to be buffered.
 * @return the current buffer used.
 */
private final byte[][] addData(final byte[] data) {
    AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]> bufArray = _bufferRef.updateAndGet(array -> {
        int idx = _arrayIdx.updateAndGet(i -> {
            return i == _size - 1 ? 0 : ++i;
        });
        byte[] expected = array.compareAndExchangeAcquire(idx, null, data);
        if (expected != null) { // should never occur, since we assume processing the buffer is faster than writing
            throw new ConcurrentCollisionException("Failed compareAndSet value '" + new String(data) + "' in " + _currBuf + ". buffer[" + idx + "]. It was set before with '" + new String(expected) + "'.");
        }
        return array;
    });
    int count = _count.incrementAndGet();

    // only one thread can execute this
    if (count % _bufferSize == 0 && count > 0) {
        int tmp = _currBuf.incrementAndGet();
        _currBuf.setPlain(tmp = tmp == _cacheSize ? 0 : tmp);
        return convert(bufArray, _bufferSize * tmp);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public final byte[][] addAndGetIfFull(final byte[] data) throws ConcurrentCollisionException {
    try {
        final byte[][] buf = addData(data); // buf is immutable
        if (buf != null) {
            _numBuf.incrementAndGet();
            resetTimer();
            return buf;
        }
    } catch (ConcurrentCollisionException e) {
        _collisions.incrementAndGet();
        addAndGetIfFull(data); // try again ??? TODO needs a 100% proof solution
    }
    return null;
}

/**
  * Converts the atomic array to a 2D byte array.
  * Any null values are pushed to the end.
  * @param array
  * @return the converted array as a 2D byte array.
  */
private final byte[][] convert(final AtomicReferenceArray<byte[]> array, int start) {
    byte[][] bd = new byte[_bufferSize][];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < _bufferSize + start; ++i, ++j) {
        byte[] val = array.getAndSet(i, null);
        if (_reorder && val == null) {
            --j;
            continue;
        }
        bd[j] = val;
    }
    if (j == 0) { // no entries
        return null;
    }
    System.out.flush();
    return bd;
}
```

`